# Set default view for PayPal payment approval

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the PayPal Adaptive Payments API in a simple (not chained or parallel) flow: payment is created, `payKey` is generated, user is redirected to payment approval URL in PayPal. Once approved, PayPal redirects the user back to my app.

The specific API call I am using is documented [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APCommands/) - the `_ap-payment` command. So the URL looks like https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=value.

I have noticed that sometimes the PayPal page the user is directed to defaults to the login view, whereas other times it defaults to the credit card info view (for submitting a CC payment via PayPal w/out logging in to a PayPal acct).

For user experience, I would like to ensure the user always sees the PayPal login view.

Anybody know if there's a way to enforce that?

(or if there's something in how I'm calling the API that triggers one view or the other that I haven't noticed yet)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable in Express Checkout called "LANDINGPAGE" which determines which payment option is the default one shown to the customer.

The two appropiate values for this variable are :

1. Billing - Pay via debit/credit card
2. Login - Pay via PayPal account

This is the only API-based variable which would allow you to customize checkout page to decide which landing page was shown to the customer first.
You can have a try.

Comment: Ok, that looks like the flag I would like to use. Do you know if it can be used with the Adaptive Payments API though?

Comment: I just make a testing , it looks like this variable can't work in adaptive payment API. sorry about that.